# Trying to make a screen that fades in and out with a button click

Tags: javascript, html, css-animations

Clicking a button should call mobileMenuToggle(), toggling an animation for mobileMenu to either fade in or fade out depending on the current status of the menu screen. When mobileMenu display is none, it should fade in, however when mobileMenu is a block, clicking the button should result in mobile menu fading out. When mobileMenu is active (block), mainBody should disappear. When mainBody is active (block), mobileMenu should disappear. Before any clicks, mobileMenu is set to "display: none"

It works the first two times the button is clicked, but on the third time it breaks. It starts playing only the fadeIn animation but both mobileMenu AND mainBody disappear. I suspect it has something to do with the event listener, but I am not really sure. Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

JS:

```
function mobileMenuToggle(){
    if (document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.display == "none"){
        document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.animationName = "fadeIn"
        document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("mainBody").style.display = "none"
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.display == "block"){
        document.getElementById("mainBody").style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.animationName = "fadeOut"
        document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.display = "block" //trigger animation

        mobileMenu.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
            document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.display = "none"
          });
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of display property, why don't you try using `visibility`. It might help with this by not taking it off the DOM completely.

Comment: `mobileMenu.addEventListener("animationend", () => {` gets added when `mobileMenuToggle` is called and the `else if` condition is true - after that EVERY animation end on that element will result in `document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.display = "none"`

Comment: try using the third argument to `addEventListener` to make the handler fire only once - as documented

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching eventlistener every time which causes unwanted behavior. Use **once:true**:

```
mobileMenu.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
        mobileMenu.style.display = "none";
    }, { once: true });
```

Besides I think `document.getElementById("mobileMenu").style.display = "block"` is unnecessary after fadeOut.

Answer (score 1):

You can use classList property with **requestAnimationFrame**:

```js
requestAnimationFrame(() => this.classList.toggle('active'))
```

> **requestAnimationFrame** allows the passed function to be executed in the
> nearest browser animation frame to ensure smoother and more efficient
> execution of animations and changes on the page.

Another example: https://dev.to/genakalinovskiy/collapse-with-requestanimationframe-api